# how do i parse environment variables with pystache?

Tags: python, python-2.7

hi i am trying to run a python shell script that will take all the environment variables and merge them into a template using pystache.
now the pystache.render command takes a dictionary argument. unfortunately os.environ does not return a dictionary.

my test case looks like this:
TEST=myTest python

```
import pystache
import os
pystache.render("{{TEST}} HELLO",os.environ)
```

any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. I'm not sure what `pystache` is doing or why `os.environ` won't work as is, but you're totally right.  This doesn't work:

```
>>> import pystache
>>> import os
>>> pystache.render("{{PATH}}",os.environ)
u''
```

But it works fine if you transform `os.environ` into a `dict`:

```
>>> import pystache
>>> import os
>>> pystache.render('{{PATH}}', dict(os.environ))
u'/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin'
```